# Periodic modules in Frobenius algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional Frobenius algebra and assume there exists an indecomposable periodic module $M$, that is $\Omega^n(M) \cong M$ for some $n$.

> Question: Does this imply that there is an indecomposable periodic module $N$ that is a submodule of $A$?